# String in the MainActivity.java file makes my Android app crash

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I added a `String` to the `MainActivity.java` file and now my app crashes as soon as I launch it (at the moment the debugger reaches the line of code with the `String`).

This is the line of code that creates the problem :

```
CharSequence Total = "Total:"; // getString(R.string.total);
```

it also creates the problem if I use `String` instead of `CharSequence`.

When I delete that line the app works perfectly.

This is the error I get in the `Gradle` console :

> `Note : /Users/ishayfrenkel1/AndroidStudioProjects/JustJava/app/src/main/java/com/howtoevery/justjava/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`

What does it mean that the app uses or overrides a deprecated API?
And how can I `Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation` in Android Studio? What does it even mean?

**The `MainActivity.java` code:**

```
    package com.howtoevery.justjava;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    CharSequence totalString = "Total:"; // getString(R.string.total);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    CharSequence toastText;
    // String total = getString(R.string.total);

    int num = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given price on the screen.
     */
    private void displayPrice(int number, CharSequence message) { // Used to be , String message
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
        priceTextView.setText(message + " " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number)); // was message before Number Format
    }

    public void addOne(View view) {
        num++;
        display(num);
        displayPrice(num*5, totalString); //used to have total
    }

    public void removeOne(View view) {
        if (num > 0) {
            num--;
            display(num);
            displayPrice(num * 5, totalString); //used to have total
        }

        else {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            toastText = getString(R.string.negativeCups);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    public void reset(View view) {
        if (num > 0) {
            num = 0;
            display(num);
            displayPrice(num, totalString); //used to have total
        }
        else {
            toastText = getString(R.string.resetted);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        displayToast(num);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    private void displayToast(int number) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        if (number > 0) {
            toastText = getString(R.string.ordering) + num + getString(R.string.ordering_cups_price) + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(num*5);
        }

        else
            toastText = getString(R.string.empty_order);


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

**This is what I get from the `logcat`:**

```
06-07 13:39:06.275  22308-22308/com.howtoevery.justjava I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-07 13:39:06.391  22308-22308/com.howtoevery.justjava D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-07 13:39:06.392  22308-22308/com.howtoevery.justjava E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.howtoevery.justjava, PID: 22308
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.howtoevery.justjava/com.howtoevery.justjava.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:105)
            at com.howtoevery.justjava.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2206)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
06-07 13:39:08.374  22308-22318/com.howtoevery.justjava W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.600ms
```

Comment: Use a different name for variable like `totalString`

Comment: @Clairvoyant That didn't help..

Comment: can you post your code to help you in better way.

Comment: Are you trying to use `getString(R.string.total)` ? Why did you comment it out?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use this, but I thought it would be easier to check the bug without referring to the `strings.xml` file

Comment: Try moving `CharSequence totalString = "Total:";` inside of your onCreate() method.

Comment: @BidhanA, the problem is that now this variable is not global and I can't reach it from outside the `onCreate()` method

Comment: Then declare the variable outside of onCreate() like `CharSequence totalString;` and then inside your onCreate(), simply do `totalString = "Total:";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your context. getApplicationContext() should be moved inside the onCreate() method. Do this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
CharSequence totalString = "Total:"; // getString(R.string.total);
Context context;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
CharSequence toastText;
// String total = getString(R.string.total);

int num = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();
}
...
```

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you :)
Can you please explain why this caused the problem or redirect me to a documentation about this please? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. getApplicationContext() provides you with the context of the current Activity. The thing is, the Activity is created only after the onCreate() method is called. So if you use getApplicationContext() before the onCreate() method, it will simply return you null because the Activity isn't even created yet!

Comment: @BidhanA calling `getApplicationContext` before `onCreate` will not return `null`. It will crash because at that point your object instance is `null` and you are invoking method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Class members initialization that takes place outside constructors/instance methods cannot use non static methods that require functional object instances, because at that point your object instance is not yet fully created. You have to move such initializations inside constructor, or instance method that you will either call from constructor or from your object reference.

You have to move initialization calls to `getString(R.string.total)`, and `getApplicationContext()` to `OnCreate` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String totalString;
    Context context;
    ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       totalString = getString(R.string.total);
       context = getApplicationContext();
    }
```

In your code, you actually don't have to grab application context at all, because you can use activity context to show your toast messages. Just refer to current activity reference with `this`

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, toastText, duration);
```

Comment: Didn't help.. The app still crashes.

Comment: Please include logcat to your question. Error is somewhere else in your code.